# Cocos2d Add photo from iphone photo album

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I want to add a sprite using the photo file of iphone. is there any simple way to do so? does cocos2d support the file system. 
is there any get method to get the photo file.

if so then what format of data does cocos receive.

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's as easy as getting an image from the UIImagePicker controller, making a texture out of it and add it to a sprite or whatever you want to do to display it.

Comment: I never worked with UI i only worked on cocos2d and chipmunk. Till it is difficult for me to communicate between UI and cocos2d So i ask for if there any coco2d method which will navigate to the phone photo album.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the UIImage using UIImagePickerController.

then you can create a CCSprite from it using the following code.

```
CCSprite *mySpriteFromImage = [CCSprite spriteWithCGImage:[myPickerImage CGImage] key:@"pickerImage"];
```